# исключение NullPointerException при работе с XML

Tags: java, xml, javafx

Пишу прогу, мне надо сохранить данные с `ObservableList` в XML, есть метод позволяющий это сделать - `handleSaveAs` но выдает исключение, я не пойму причину, помогите разобраться.

```
/**
     * Открывает FileChooser, чтобы пользователь имел возможность
     * выбрать файл, куда будут сохранены данные
     */
    @FXML
    private void handleSaveAs() {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        // Задаём фильтр расширений
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
                "XML files (*.xml)", "*.xml");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

        // Показываем диалог сохранения файла
        File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(main.getPrimaryStage());  //Жалуется на эту строку

        if (file != null) {
            // Make sure it has the correct extension
            if (!file.getPath().endsWith(".xml")) {
                file = new File(file.getPath() + ".xml");
            }
            main.saveDataDataToFile(file);
        }
    }
```

Исключение

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at zaryadye.controller.MenuBarController.handleSaveAs(MenuBarController.java:90)
    ... 53 more
```

main - ссылка на главное приложение, и ниже методы методы которые я так же использую

```
 /**
 * Возвращаем главную сцену.
 * @return
 */
public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return menuBar;
}

/**
 * Сохраняет текущую информацию об адресатах в указанном файле.
 *
 * @param file
 */
public void saveDataDataToFile(File file) {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(DataListWrapper.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        // Обёртываем наши данные об адресатах.
        DataListWrapper wrapper = new DataListWrapper();
        wrapper.setMainData(contractData); //и тут

        // Маршаллируем и сохраняем XML в файл.
        m.marshal(wrapper, file);

        // Сохраняем путь к файлу в реестре.
        setDataFilePath(file);
    } catch (Exception e) { // catches ANY exception
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("Could not save data");
        alert.setContentText("Could not save data to file:\n" + file.getPath());

        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Comment: В какой именно строке исключение?

Comment: @AntonSorokin наверное надо было это как-то отдельно выделить,
строка - `File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(main.getPrimaryStage());`
это первый блок кода

Comment: Тогда у вас либо `fileChooser = null`, либо `main`. Я у вас кстати не увидел инициализации `main`.

Comment: @AntonSorokin main не может быть null, я его много где использую, а на счет fileChooser, проверю еще конечно

Comment: Ну что, проверили? Просто поставьте `if(fileChooser == null) S.o.pln("null")`.

Comment: @AntonSorokin да, я в данный метот прописал как Вы предложили, в консоли `null` не рпописывается, так же `main` проверил